# Python math division operation returns 0

Tags: python, division

```
print "------------ EPIDEMIOLOGY --------------\n"

def divide(A,B):
    return A/B

print " [Population] point Prevalence rate: "
A = input("Enter value for people with disease: " )
B = input("Enter value for total population: " )    
prevalence = divide(A,B)
print " Population Prevalence rate is: ",prevalence
```

A and B are user input and do not know if they are integers or floats. My answer is always 0 when i run this program. (I'm new in Python). How do i fix this or change in my function to avoid this problem?

the input part of code works, the math does not.

Comment: Try adding: `print type(A), repr(A), type(B), repr(B)` after the `input`s, so you know what you've actually got. I don't know what you actually entered, but your program can tell you.

Answer (score 7):

You get the answer `0` because you are using Python2 and performing integer division. The fact that the population with disease cannot be higher than the total population is the reason that you get zero for every reasonable input (except when both values are the same).

Two fixes:

```
def divide(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        # decide for yourself what should happen here
    else:
        return float(a)/b
```

This will make sure that your function performs floating point division, not matter what numbers you pass to it. The second fix is that you should use `raw_input` in Python2 and cast the input to a number (`float` would be fine here).

```
a = float(raw_input("Enter value for people with disease: ")) # add error checking as needed
b = float(raw_input("Enter value for total population: " )) # add error checking as needed
```

The problem with `input()` is that it is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

Comment: @EvErlton no problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 4):

In python 2.x is performed integer division. If dividend is less than divisor, the operation returns zero.
So you have two options:

### Make one of operands as float:

```
def divide(A,B):
    return float(A)/B
```

### import feature from Python 3

```
from __future__ import division

print "------------ EPIDEMIOLOGY --------------\n"

def divide(A,B):
    return A/B
```

Comment: Upvoted for suggesting `from __future__ import division`. Always nice to get people used to writing Py3 code (and giving them reasons to choose it over Py2). :-)

Comment: @EvErlton: FYI, you can perform that `__future__` import and still get floor division when needed. The `//` operator is always available (in Py2.2+), and _always_ (with or without `__future__` `division` import) means floor division, so you can use `/` for "natural" division (gets `float` w/decimal) and `//` for floor division (drops decimal). It's a good habit to get into, always using `//` when you're doing int -> int division; w/o it, the `2to3` converter can't reliably distinguish `/` for at least one `float` value (true division) from `/` for two `int` values (truncating division).

Comment: If you perform the `__future__` import, code that is mathematically correct in Py2 is guaranteed to remain so in Py3; without it, `2to3` heuristics are "best guess". As a rule, all Py2 code I write begins with `from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function` (and often imports `unicode_literals` as well) to ease eventual porting to Py3.